# Why when I ping the FQDN of an EvenHub in Azure I get three different IP addreses?

Tags: azure, ping

I got connectivity problems with azure behind a firewall, so I made an script to ping every one minute.

Why when I ping the FQDN of an EvenHub in azure I get three different IP addreses?
why there are 3?

I got another eventHub, different FQDN an there is only one IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how Azure choose to configure it in that instance. They give you a FQDN, not an IP for a reason: they run a massive operation, and may switch things around for reasons such as load balancing, outages or similar.

You should *not* rely on whitelisting IP's. Many firewalls support regularly resolving domains into IP's so you can in effect whitelist a FQDN, and the FW will handle updating the rules to match the actual IP's.